# coffeescript error: 'unexpected .' for console.log

Tags: coffeescript

Have no idea why I am getting this error but my code:

```
angular.module('authAppApp')
  .factory 'AuthService', (Session) ->
    # Service logic
    # ...



    # Public API here
    {
      login: (creds)->


        res =  
              id: 1, 
              user: 
                id: 1,
                role: "admin"



            Session.create(res.id, res.user.id, res.user.role)
            return 


    }
```

Error:

```
[stdin]:30:14: error: unexpected .
            Session.create(res.id, res.user.id, res.user.role)
             ^
```

This also happens with `console.log`
Why?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your indentation is off:

```
    res =  
          id: 1, 
          user: 
            id: 1,
            role: "admin"



        Session.create(res.id, res.user.id, res.user.role)
        return
```

The indentation of `Session` should match the indentation of `res =`. Otherwise, the coffeescript compiler will parse it as a property of the object you are setting `res` to. In particular, it's probably expecting a `:` and a value after `Session`.